# Vite forwad POST request to GET

Tags: vite

Here is my vite config

```
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://xxx.xxx.inc",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => {
          return path.replace(/^\/api/, "");
        },
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
```

When I post a data, weired things happend!

The POST was "301 Moved Permanently" And it became GET!

```
 vite:proxy /api/core/login -> https://xxx.xxx.inc +0ms
  vite:time 475.67ms /core/login +10s
  vite:spa-fallback Not rewriting GET /core/login/ because the client prefers JSON. +10s
  vite:time 0.73ms /core/login/ +7ms
  vite:proxy /api/core/login -> https://xxx.xxx.inc +15m
  vite:time 476.08ms /core/login +15m
  vite:spa-fallback Not rewriting GET /core/login/ because the client prefers JSON. +15m
  vite:time 0.66ms /core/login/ +5ms
```

For Proxy server,

> A POST should be always POST after